# How to convert rows of a dataframe into columns with a different name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like

| Name | Class | id | C-id | Main ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | XC | 1 | 1 | M1 |
| ZTC | CVF | 2 | 1 | M1 |
| ABK1 | XCD | 1 | 2 | M1 |
| ZTH1 | CVFD | 2 | 2 | M1 |

I want the output to look like that

| Name | Class | Name_m | Class_m | C-id | Main ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | XC | ZTC | CVF | 1 | M1 |
| ABK1 | XCD | ZTH1 | CVFD | 2 | M1 |

Can someone please suggest how I can accomplish this with the least hardcoding possible.

One idea I have is to separate the records with id=1 and id =2 and merge again

Comment: why ZTC is name_m for Name ABC?

Comment: Because they have the same ci-d and Main Id

Answer (score 0):

This will get you what you want, but I guess if you explain more about your logic and how your data looks then it will be easier to understand how to generalise it.

```
(df
 .groupby('id')
 .get_group(1)
 .reset_index(drop=True)
 .merge(
     df
     .groupby('id')
     .get_group(2)[['Name', 'Class']]
     .reset_index(drop=True)
     .add_suffix('_m'), 
     left_index=True, right_index=True)
.drop(columns=['id'])
)
```

Or in smaller steps:

```
a = df.groupby('id').get_group(1).reset_index(drop=True)
b = df.groupby('id').get_group(2)[['Name', 'Class']].reset_index(drop=True).add_suffix('_m')
a.merge(b, left_index=True, right_index=True).drop(columns=['id'])
```

Comment: This doen't satisfy the OP's desire to produce columns of [Name, Class, Name_m, Class_m ,  C-id, Main ID].  Your solution only produces [Name, Class, id, C-id, Main ID]

Comment: that's incorrect, did you run it?

Comment: yes I did run the first version but not the second using smaller steps

Comment: I just ran the second version and it in fact gives correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that @Josh Friedlander can update his solution to produce the exact columns you need.  In the mean time, this is another approach:

```
dfm = df[df['id'] == 1].merge(df[df['id'] == 2], on="C-id", how='inner')
dfm = dfm.rename(columns={'Name_x': 'Name', 'Class_x': 'Class', 'Name_y': 'Name_m', 'Class_y': 'Class_m', 'Main ID_y': 'Main ID'})
dfm.drop(['id_x', 'id_y', 'Main ID_x'], inplace=True, axis=1)
dfm
```

Yields:

```
   Name    Class    C-id    Name_m  Class_m Main ID
0   ABC     XC       1      ZTC     CVF     M1
1   ABK1    XCD      2      ZTH1    CVFD    M1
```